# Windows Azure Scheduler Job Completed Unexpectedly

Tags: azure, azure-scheduler

I created a job recently to run, every hour continuously.

However after 14 runs, it then has a status of Completed and no Next Run Time.

Is there something I am missing. Why would a scheduled job with no end date just move to the completed status?

Disabling and Enabling Jobs doesn't make any difference. I can't seem to restart it, I can't even edit it.

There are no faults or execution errors. It is a job that sends a message to an Azure Storage Queue.

The only option I have is to delete it and create again, but will it just stop again after a period of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like my own mistake here. At the moment in the UI there is no way to set a null end date, hence it defaults to a set date and time, which is 12am for the next day, hence my 14 hours.

Hopefully they upgrade this UI soon, so much potential for this system, already designing my systems to use it.

In the meantime my end date is now scheduled to end in 20 years, I would assume Azure would have allow null end times by then.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler on Azure Mobile Services is more mature, but costs more too.  There, if all you're needing is the scheduler - you're having to pay for all the other mobile services stuff too.  I frankly do not understand why Microsoft would even put this in "preview" status without at least allowing us to view and edit our scheduled jobs.  Very odd.